# How to create Triggers in MySQL workbench that limit what values can be entered into certain columns?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a trigger in MySQL workbench that limits what values can be entered into certain columns. Specifically, I want to limit certain columns to only have values between 0.00 and 100.00.

I have already tried creating the trigger using the following code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER rate_as_percentage
BEFORE INSERT ON loans
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    LoanTranche_A_rate (%) BETWEEN 0.00 AND 100.00,
    LoanTranche_B_rate (%) BETWEEN 0.00 AND 100.00,
    LoanTranche_C_rate (%) BETWEEN 0.00 AND 100.00,
    LoanTranche_D_rate (%) BETWEEN 0.00 AND 100.00,
    LoanTranche_E_rate (%) BETWEEN 0.00 AND 100.00,
END;
```

I want the trigger to be called rate_as_percentage and the LoanTranche_A-E are the columns I want to control.

Comment: (%) will cause a syntax error in mysql - what did you think it might do?

Comment: The (%) is part of the column name, so people know the unit of the numbers in that column.